# Get multiple parameters using query_vars

Tags: php, wordpress

In functions.php

```
function add_query_vars_uniqlo($aVars) {
    $aVars[] = array("qtext",
                     "qbrand",
                    "qnew",
                    "qdiscount",
                    "qlimit",
                    "qmulti",
                    "qonline",
                    "qspsize",
                    "qrange",
                    "qcolor",
                    "qsize",
                    "qicon",
                    "qstart",
                    "sort",
                    "qclv1",
                    "uniqlo_url");

    return $aVars;
}
// hook add_query_vars function into query_vars
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars_uniqlo');
```

How do I get the parameters supposed that the url has all the parameters? In my theme php file. I use

```
global $wp_query;
$aVars[] = array("qtext",
                     "qbrand",
                    "qnew",
                    "qdiscount",
                    "qlimit",
                    "qmulti",
                    "qonline",
                    "qspsize",
                    "qrange",
                    "qcolor",
                    "qsize",
                    "qicon",
                    "qstart",
                    "sort",
                    "qclv1",
                    "uniqlo_url");

if(isset($wp_query->query_vars($aVars))) { //Do some thing}
```

Is `$wp_query->query_vars($aVars)` correct?

Comment: where are you getting ? you are adding parameters to query vars.

Comment: so how do I get the parameters?

Comment: use [get_query_var](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)

Comment: but in many tutorial, they use $wp_query->query_vars($aVars) to get the parameters. http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/

Comment: yes there is also a function that you can get it from.